# Swift: How to create global dictionary and fetch dictionary values in swiftui view

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to create a global dictionary in swift that i can access anywhere in the project.

I tried this

```js
struct Global {
    static var productList = [Product]() 
}
```

```js
struct Product: Hashable {
    let name: String
    let aisleNo:Int
    let location_section: Int
    let location_zone: String
    let productPrice: Int
}
```

this is each product property that i would like to add to dictionary with each product key being the _id property

```js
         _id = 5f2158f71439a1549ab32cc9;
        _partitionKey = store=storename;
        productBrand = Ocean's Halo;
        productDept = Food;
        productDescription = Ocean's Halo Water Watermelon Lime;
        productImg = http://i5.walmartimages.com/asr/75a59918-8f1b-4b79-8b35-15a919981e5c_2.5efe5f0ccff7abaa7831c3795003fd93.png?odnHeight=180&odnWidth=180&odnBg=ffffff;
        productImg1 = /ip/Ocean-s-Halo-Deep-Sea-Water-Watermelon-Lime-16oz/866033215;
        productLocation_aisle = 14;
        productLocation_section = 1;
        productLocation_zone = A;
        productName = Ocean's Halo Deep Sea Water, Watermelon Lime, 16oz;
        productPrice = 2.97;
        productRating = 4.2;
        productUPC = List<string> <0x282252080> (
            [0] 00811670030224
        );
        product_stock_status = Limited Stock;
        storeProductId = 1TFNSLXLW0QP;
        store_available = store;
    }
```

i try to add to the Global productList with this function

```js
class SearchResult : ObservableObject {





func listItem() {

 for product in productArray {
            let productName = product.productName!
            let aisleNo = product.productLocation_aisle.value!
            let location_section = product.productLocation_section.value!
            let location_zone = product.productLocation_zone!
            let productPrice =  product.productPrice.value!
            let product_real_id = product._id!
            
            Global.productList.append(Product(name: productName, aisleNo: aisleNo, location_section: location_section, location_zone: location_zone, productPrice: Int(productPrice)))

}


}
```

the problem with this is that I want the dictionary key to be an objectId so that  products are not duplicated and be able to access the dictionary in swiftui view

```js
struct SearchResultView: View {
    
    var searchResults = [Global.productList]
    

    
        var body: some View {
               VStack {
                Text("Let's see where ")
//                for prodItem in searchResults {
//                    Text(prodItem).bold()
//                }

              
            }     
           }
    

}
```

How could I add product to Global dictionary with objectId as key and then fetch each product in swiftUI view?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look into using [@EnvironmentObject](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/environmentobject). It can be used exactly for what you want.

You could create an instance of your product list in your main ContentView for example. You can then pass the allocated product list by using the `.environmentObject()` annotation when creating your view hierarchy.

A simple example:

```
var productList = [Product]() 

var body: some View {
     ProductView {
    }.environmentObject(productList)
}
```

Do some searching for how to use EnvironmentObject. As your data model becomes more complex you can look into using Combine as well to help propogate changes to your data across your view hierarchy.